Imports in Nuxt with @ or ~, which is better?
In Nuxt 3, imports can reference the project root using either ~ or @, for example:
import SubHeader from "@/components/SubHeader.vue"

vs
import SubHeader from "~/components/SubHeader.vue"

Is there a functional difference between these? Is one preferred over the other?

None. Use relative path. They are the only valid specifiers per ecmascript specification. Everything else will make you regret it later.

@EricMORAND invalid answer in this context + quite a big shift as  a whole too. Also, nowadays it's properly resolved.

@kissu that's why it is not an answer, but a comment. Also, no, it is not properly resolved. It violates the specification of the language.

Both @ and ~ are valid in Nuxt, you can choose what you prefer.
It is worth mentioning that the core members of Nuxt prefer ~ because it is much safer in edge cases where @ has special meaning in toolings. You can see now that the official docs only use ~ in the examples.
Ref: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/pull/24574#issuecomment-1841628599
